# Проблема с подключением в гойс чат бота discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, async-await

Взял код с документации, но он не работает, так же пытался шаманить над ним, но не вышло, поскажите пожалуйста с чем это может быть связано? Именно не работает подключение в войс чат, зависает программа

```
import asyncio
import os

import discord
import youtube_dl
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        """Joins a voice channel"""

        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)

        await channel.connect()
        print('doesn\'t work')

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
        """Plays a file from the local filesystem"""

        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {query}')

    @commands.command()
    async def yt(self, ctx, *, url):
        """Plays from a url (almost anything youtube_dl supports)"""

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def stream(self, ctx, *, url):
        """Streams from a url (same as yt, but doesn't predownload)"""

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def volume(self, ctx, volume: int):
        """Changes the player's volume"""

        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("Not connected to a voice channel.")

        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = volume / 100
        await ctx.send(f"Changed volume to {volume}%")

    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        """Stops and disconnects the bot from voice"""

        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @play.before_invoke
    @yt.before_invoke
    @stream.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"),
    description='Relatively simple music bot example',
    intents=intents,
)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')


async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
        await bot.start(os.getenv('TOKEN'))


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Какая ошибка вы наверное написать не соизволите...

Comment: @DaYa Её нет, просто зависает компилятор, для теста совал после `await channel.connect` -> `print('doesn\'t work')` и ничего не выводило, и не срабатывало

Comment: То есть вы вызываете команду так: <пинг бота> join, *, channel и ожидаемого результата не происходит?

Comment: @DaYa <пинг бота> join channel_id, я вписывал так

Comment: У меня всё работает, мой голосовой канал называется "." я прописал <пинг бота> join . и всё заработало, позже я проверил c id вместо названия и аналогично всё работает. Попробуйте прописать с названием вместо id.

Comment: @DaYa Сделал ровно так же, и все равно не работает, так же убрал 2 последних аргумента и создал переменную `channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel` и все равно не работает(и запрос делаю такой <пинг бота> join) :/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141308/discussion-between-daya-and-degri).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот этот кусочек кода.

```
async def play(ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if connected:
        await connected.channel.connect()
```

А потом выполните все необходимые шаги:

```
        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {query}')
```

[image: Пример входа в войс]

Comment: Не работает, постоянно зависает на этом моменте `await connected.channel.connect()` или на этом `await channel.connect()` перепробовал уже все что можно, не знаю в чем причина :/

Comment: @Degri в таком случае я тоже не знаю. Попробуйте найти ошибку в интернете, либо отправьте сюда код, быть может помогу. В любом случае сам код работает, я сам его использую.